# Measure or column filtered by a relationship and a slicer

Tags: powerbi, dax, data-analysis, dimensional-modeling, slicers

I have a table `Deals` which has columns `[DealId]`, `[Open Date Id]`, `[Closed Date Id]` where the last 2 columns are like a foreign key to the `Date` table which has `[Date]`, `[DateId]` column.

Power BI won't let me have 2 active relationship, so one is inactive.

Now I want to create some visuals indicating the deals that were open and closed in a custom range of time (using slicer).

**How I tried to solve**

The closest solution to this was creating a calculated column with the `LOOKUPVALUE` and adding the close and open dates directly to Deals table. And created 2 different pages with 2 different slicers, but this is far not the solution I wanted.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if what I'm going to say suits your needs based on the size of the tables or the rigidity of the data model due to other measures. I think that in the end what matters is to understand what are the limitations of what you want to show. However, something almost similar I answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66792957/15460989

From what I could understand you have two tables similar to:

```
Deals = {[DealID] [OpenDate] [CloseDate] [Quantity] [Price] ...}
Dates = {[Date] [MonthName] [MonthNumber] [Year] ...}
```

And you want to filter Deals based on two relationships

```
USERELATIONSHIP (Dates [Date], Deals [OpenDate])
USERELATIONSHIP (Dates [Date], Deals [CloseDate])
```

I am not going to discuss the option of duplicating Dates Table because it was previously covered using two slicers.

But what if the characteristics of my model allow me to use a table with two relationship (One active and the other inactive) while my visualization uses the content of an unrelated table?

Let's define my new unrelated table as:

```
HarvestingDates = {[Date] [MonthName] [MonthNumber] [Year] ...}
```

and what I'm trying to achieve is something like this:

[image]

From a model like this one:

[image]

```
Deals[DealID]: Unique values.
Deals[OpenDate]: Repeated and missing dates
Deals[CloseDate]: A random number between 0 and 5 is added to Deals [OpenDate]
```

Instead of choosing an opening date and a closing date, I choose a date range not related to the model and the context related to the deals comes from the measures. Example:

Opened Deals: All the deals opened in a certain date range and summarized by the visualization.

```
HOpenedDeals: =
CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS(Deals), 
        TREATAS(
        VALUES(HarvestingDate[Date]),Dates[Date]
        )
)
```

Closed Deals: All the deals closed in a certain date range and summarized by the visualization.

```
HClosedDeals:=
CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS(Deals),
    USERELATIONSHIP(Dates[Date],Deals[CloseDate]),
    TREATAS(VALUES(HarvestingDate[Date]),Dates[Date])
)
```

Open and closed deals: All open and closed deals in the same date range summarized by the visualization

```
HOpened&Closed := 
VAR TotalRow= SUMMARIZE(HarvestingDate,HarvestingDate[Year],HarvestingDate[MonthName])
VAR CurrentDates=VALUES(HarvestingDate[Date])
VAR Result=
ADDCOLUMNS(TotalRow, "Count",
VAR CurrentMonthName= {CALCULATE(VALUES(HarvestingDate[MonthName]))}
VAR CurrentYear= {CALCULATE(VALUES(HarvestingDate[Year]))}
RETURN
COUNTROWS(INTERSECT(
                CALCULATETABLE(Deals,
                USERELATIONSHIP(Dates[Date],Deals[CloseDate]),
                TREATAS(CurrentMonthName, Dates[MonthName]),
                TREATAS(CurrentYear, Dates[Year]),
                TREATAS(CurrentDates, Dates[Date])
                ),
                CALCULATETABLE(Deals,
                TREATAS(CurrentMonthName, Dates[MonthName]),
                TREATAS(CurrentYear, Dates[Year]),
                TREATAS(CurrentDates, Dates[Date])
                )
                )))
RETURN SUMX(Result,[Count])
```

Opened & Not Closed Deals: All open and non-closed deals in the same date range summarized by visualization

```
HO&NOTC := 
VAR TotalRow= SUMMARIZE(HarvestingDate,HarvestingDate[Year],HarvestingDate[MonthName])
VAR CurrentDates=VALUES(HarvestingDate[Date])
VAR Result=
ADDCOLUMNS(TotalRow, "Count",
VAR CurrentMonthName= {CALCULATE(VALUES(HarvestingDate[MonthName]))}
VAR CurrentYear= {CALCULATE(VALUES(HarvestingDate[Year]))}
RETURN
COUNTROWS(EXCEPT(
                CALCULATETABLE(Deals,
                TREATAS(CurrentMonthName, Dates[MonthName]),
                TREATAS(CurrentYear, Dates[Year]),
                TREATAS(CurrentDates, Dates[Date])
                ),
                CALCULATETABLE(Deals,
                USERELATIONSHIP(Dates[Date],Deals[CloseDate]),
                TREATAS(CurrentMonthName, Dates[MonthName]),
                TREATAS(CurrentYear, Dates[Year]),
                TREATAS(CurrentDates, Dates[Date])
                )
                )))
RETURN SUMX(Result,[Count])
```

TEST

```
Date range: {5/27/2021…5/31/2021}
```

[image]

I am sure this can be improved but as I said at the beginning it is just an idea. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

In this case the easiest way is to implement a **role playing dimension** functionality by duplicating your date table. Power BI engine does not support role playing dimensions, so the workaround for small tables is just duplicating them, as described in [this article](https://radacad.com/scenarios-of-using-calculated-tables-in-power-bi).

In your case, you could create a table "Date_for_closed" using

```
Date_for_closed = ALL('Date')
```

This creates a copy of your original Date table. Then you can create relationships and only have active ones. This way it is even easier to maintain than a bunch of inactive relationships.

[image]

With this implemented you can build this:

[image]

from this source:

[image]

Comment: Thank you!
So, there is no way to have one single Date slicer for the both Closed and Open date id?
Maybe there is a way to make one slicer dependent to another, and make one invisible if this is possible? I don't know if this is even possible, since I am new to PowerBi :)

Comment: This is a good question. I have always used slicers to slice only one field, so what I can tell, I just cannot think of a way to do it right now. Probably it could be possible, but not without some data rearrangements - additional columns, etc. But even in this case, I just don't know now.